# What happens when preprocessor lines are processed by the preprocessor? - the '.i' file

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am using **Gnu cc compiler of Gcc** to compile my C programs. Consider a program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when I pre-process the above code, using

```
cpp sample.c > sample.i
```

I get a lot of contents in **sample.i** which I haven't included. Say, 'stdio.h' file is preprocessed. If that is the case,

**Question 1:**

Why are there so many lines in my preprocessed file? I **haven't used any of the standard library functions nor Macros.**

**Question 2:**

Can anyone explain what exactly happens when the preprocessor proccess the C file.(The contents that I got in my '*.i' file)

Compiler: gcc

OS: Ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: It literally opens the include file, and copies the contents in-place. If `<stdio.h>` also `#include`s some other files, those also get copied in, and so on. That's why you get so much stuff you didn't think you asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are there so many lines in my preprocessed file? I haven't used any of the standard library functions nor Macros.

Preprocessing is just one part of the compilation process. It's more or less a simple textual replacement and nothing more complex is involved at the preprocessing stage. The preprocessor does not know or care whether you have used any standard functions in your code program or not. An optimizer (as part of the compilation process) might 
"remove" parts that are not needed. But the preprocessor doesn't do that.
It'll do preprocessing of all the header files you have included and other header files included via your header files and so on.

> Can anyone explain what exactly happens when the preprocessor process the C file.(The contents that I got in my '*.i' file)

The preprocessing involves quite a few tasks: macro replacement, conditional compilation, stringification, string concatenation etc.
You can read more about `cpp` in detail here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/

Answer (score 3):

the preprocessor command `#include "aFile.h"` will put the hole content from `aFile.h` into your cpp file. And that exactly to the place, where the preprocessor directives stands. That is the reason why you can use the in `aFile.h` defined functions.

if you are interest to learn more about the preprocessor, there is a very good (and short) guidance on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Comment: Why copying contents of stdio.h file, while I haven't used anything that is related to it(no library functions or Macros)?

Comment: Preprocessor does not care.

Comment: you don't use it yet, but you could. If you don't need them, you can remove the include statement.

Comment: @PantherCoder The preprocessor doesn't parse your code. It only cares about directives and macro replacement. It couldn't remove unused declaration even if it tried.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor does text substitution.   The net effect of `#include <stdio.h>` is to replace the `#include <stdio.h>` line with the contents of `<stdio.h>`.

Practically, `<stdio.h>` contains several declarations of various functions (e.g. `fprintf()`, `fscanf()`), declarations of variables (e.g. `stdout`, `stdin`), and some macro definitions (which, when used in later code, cause text substitution).

The preprocessor is specified as a phase of compilation, which takes source code as input, substitutes text as required (e.g. the `#include` as I have described, macro expansions, etc), and outputs the resultant source code.  That output is what you are directing into sample.i

The output of the preprocessor is then input to a later phase of compilation, which actually understands declarations, definitions, statements, etc.

The phases of compilation are sequential - they occur one after the other, not all at once.  So the later phase of compilation feeds no information whatsoever back to the preprocessor.   It is the later phase of compilation that detects if declarations etc are used.  But, since it cannot feed such information back to the preprocessor (and the preprocessor is an ignorant program that couldn't use such information anyway) the preprocessor cannot know that declarations are unused, and filter them out.

Answer (score 1):

1) You may not use them, but you have included them  in line 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

That's where what you see come from. Try to remove it to see the difference.

2) The preprocessor read your C file and processed all preprocessor directives that you have declared. All Preprocessor directives start with a '#' symbol. The '#include' will replace this line by the content of the given file. You also have the classical '#ifndef' and '#define' directive. The latter is equal to 'if' statement which allow you to activate a part of a code only if a symbol is defined

```
#ifndef _SOME_SYMBOL_
#define _SOME_SYMBOL_

#ifndef WIN32
 #include <some_file.h>
#else
 #include <some_other_file.h>
#endif

int main() { return 0;}

#endif //endof _SOME_SYMBOL_

#ifndef _SOME_SYMBOL_ 
#define _SOME_SYMBOL_

// this second function is ignored
int main() { return 0;}

#endif //endof _SOME_SYMBOL_
```

When the preprocessor reads the above file, the symbol "_SOME_SYMBOL_" is unknown, so the preprocessor initializes it. Next it includes the file whether or not it knows of `WIN32`. Usually this kind of symbol is passed trough command line. So part of your code is dynamically activated or deactivated.

The preprocessor will output this

```
void some_other_function_from_some_other_file(){}

int main() { return 0;}
```